# How to brace misaligned support post?

Tags: foundation, post, beam

Recently purchased a new home, and after removing the builder insulation blanket we discovered that one of the support posts has become (or always has been) misaligned and isn't resting on the beam.

My thoughts to remedy the gap is to hammer in a few "squish" plates. But I'm at a bit of a loss as to how to brace the misalignment. [image]

Comment: My apologies! Yes, I meant "post". Question edited. The gap is between the post (floor jack) and beam. It's about 1/2".

Comment: I think I'd be investigating why a post, which presumably carries thousands of pounds of structure, is... floating. What's at the other end?

Comment: My best guess would be that it's attached to the beam above with a hangar.

Comment: What beam? Post and beams aren't connected with hangers. Their may be lag screws, however.

Comment: I'm not at home right now. Otherwise I would take a photo. But there are instances in our current house, and our previous where support posts were both resting on it's support and attached to the beam using a bracket.

Comment: My point is that I don't think I'd be shimming until I was confident that the post should be raised.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/81009/discussion-between-pimbrouwers-and-isherwood).